# Can't override a function's inner variable

Tags: javascript, math

Just me and my noob questions again. Trying to pass variables from event listeners inside a function and calculate their product (right now just logging them). Here's what it looks like:

```
getFactors(){
    document.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if(e.target.className === "radio_custom_label"){
            e.stopPropagation()
            this.doTheMath({first: e.target.getAttribute("for").split("_").pop()})
        }
    })
    document.addEventListener("change", e => {
        if(e.target.id === "license_amount"){
            this.doTheMath({second: parseInt(e.target.value)})
        }
    })
}

doTheMath(params){
    var one = 13;
    var two = 1;
    one = (params.first !== undefined)?params.first:one
    two = (params.second !== undefined)?params.second:two

    console.log(one,two)
}
```

First is getting input from a radio button group (their ids, which are 'radio_' 13, 22 and 34), second is a select-option dropdown - an array from 1 to 10. Passing an object because variables are in separate listeners, don't want to declare null for absent parameter.

- What I expected:

  - Defaults are 13 and 1. I select the second radio button, now the values are 22 and 1.
  - I select, say, option 5 from dropdown, now it's 22 and 5.
  - I switch from second radio button to first, I have 13 and 5.
- What I got:

  - Defaults 13 and 1, I select radio-2, that makes the variables 22 and 1 respectively.
  - Selecting option 4, I expect 22 and 4. Instead, it's 13 and 4.
  - Changing to radio-3. 34 and 4? No, 34 and 1.

Why aren't they being overwritten by the incoming arguments? Tried regular conditionals, same result.
Thank you very much for your time, even if it's trivial.

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh, that. Yes, there's only one license_amount, the dropdown

Comment: Everytime you call the `doTheMath()` function, it resets. It doesn't remember the input from the last call. You call it when you change the radio group. So it does what you expect. Then you call it by changing the select. But it no longer "knows" what happened during the first call

Comment: If you want to keep the values then look up closures and how they work. e.g. let doTheMath = (makeDoTheMath(){
    var one = 13;
    var two = 1;
return function(params){
    one = (params.first !== undefined)?params.first:one
    two = (params.second !== undefined)?params.second:two

    console.log(one,two)
}})();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in `doTheMath` is persistent; one call of it won't "save" the variables for the next call.

Consider the listeners (which can be reduced into one) call a function which retrieves both values, then calls `doTheMath` with both:

```
attachListeners() {
  document.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (e.target.matches('#license_amount, .radio')) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      getValues();
    }
  })
}
getValues() {
  const radioValue = document.querySelector('.radio:checked')?.value ?? 13;
  const selectValue = document.querySelector('#license_amount').value || 1;
  this.doTheMath({
    radioValue,
    selectValue
  });
}
doTheMath({ radioValue, selectValue }) {
  console.log(radioValue, selectValue);
}
```

The radio button change will trigger a `change` event that you can listen for, so it'll work for both the radio button and the select.

Tweak the `.matches` call so that it properly selects the radio button (eg, if the radio buttons have a `radio` class, use the selector in the code above).

```js
class X {
  attachListeners() {
    document.addEventListener("change", e => {
      if (e.target.matches('#license_amount, .radio')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.getValues();
      }
    })
  }
  getValues() {
    const radioValue = document.querySelector('.radio:checked')?.value ?? -1;
    const selectValue = document.querySelector('#license_amount').value || 77;
    this.doTheMath({
      radioValue,
      selectValue
    });
  }
  doTheMath({ radioValue, selectValue }) {
    console.log(radioValue, selectValue);
  }
}
const x = new X();
x.attachListeners();
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="foo" value="1">
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="foo" value="2">
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="foo" value="3">

<select id="license_amount">
  <option></option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
  <option value="66">66</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Big thank you, that solved it! I'll take this knowledge for the future. Didn't think of using .matches(), didn't realise I could use "change" on both the radio group and select dropdown. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

why not you conditionally set the values on the variables one and two;

for example var one = params.first || 13.

also, try printing the params to the console to be sure the params are been sent. Hope this helps though

Comment: that's the point - params arrive, but there's only one per event, like {first:22} or {second:8}. It's going to be the same - the variable not getting the parameter will reset to default, 13 and 1. I just want to leave it unchanged, with a previous value, if no parameter arrives. If first was 22, and {second:8) comes in, first should remain 22, not default to 13

Answer (score 0):

This is totally expected. Each time you run `this.doTheMath()` you are making a new function call and you only pass either `params.one` or `params.two`. So every time this function runs, it only has one of the two params set and it uses the default for the other one.

Functions don't store values from their previous calls. Each function call runs independently with the parameters you give it.

You have some options to make it work.

1. Pass both params to each call (preferred)

```
//Inside the first listener
this.doTheMath({
   first: e.target.getAttribute("for").split("_").pop(),
   second: document.querySelector('#license_amount').value
})

//Inside the second listener
this.doTheMath({
   first: document.querySelector('.radio_custom_label').getAttribute("for").split("_").pop(),
   second: parseInt(e.target.value)
})
```

2. Store your values outside the functions

Comment: Thank you, the answer above made me realise I could unite both listeners into one. That fixed the issue of calling the same function twice